# The transition function of the normal bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let's consider the projective spaces $CP^{1}$ and $CP^{2}$.Suppose $CP^{1}$ is the subspace of $CP^{2}$,then we have the normal bundle of $CP^{1}$ in $CP^{2}$. My question is that how can we get the transition functions of this normal bundle under the standard cover of projective space.

I know that the normal bundle should be the tangent vectors which are perpendicular to the tangent spaces of submanifold intuitively.Locally $CP^{1}$ in $CP^{2}$ is like $C^{1}$ in $C^{2}$ .At this point ,I don't know how to continue in accurate math language? Is my idea right or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You would need to work with bases for tangent spaces (for both $\Bbb P^1$ and $\Bbb P^2$) in the two open sets. But, even better, I recommend you consider the *conormal* bundle (the bundle of $1$-forms on $\Bbb P^2$ along $\Bbb P^1$ annihilating the tangent space of $\Bbb P^1$). Note that if locally $\Bbb P^1\subset\Bbb P^2$ is cut out by $f=0$ (with $0$ a regular value) then $df$ gives a nowhere-zero section of the conormal bundle in that open set.

Comment: To complement Ted, I'd observe that the total space of the normal bundle of a line in $\mathbf{CP}^{2}$ embeds _holomorphically_ as the complement of a point. It's then clear the normal bundle is the hyperplane bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$: perturbing the line by an automorphism of the plane gives a holomorphic section of the normal bundle.